# Percorrer JSON para construção de gráfico waterfall D3

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso construir um gráfico em *waterfall* e estou tendo problemas ao percorrer o *JSON* para construir esse gráfico.

```
data =  {
"key": "Margem bruta",
"total": 30000,
"value": [
  {
    "name": "Gastos com pessoal",
    "value": -3700
  },
  {
    "name": "Outros rendimentos e gastos",
    "value": -1800
  },
  {
    "key": "Lucro de vendas",
    "total": 25100,
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "Gastos de depreciação e amortização",
        "value": -13400
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Lucro com serviços",
    "total": 11700,
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "Juros suportados",
        "value": -3700
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "key": "Lucro de ações",
    "total": 7100,
    "value": [
      {
        "name": "Imposto sobre rendimento",
        "value": -3300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Resultado liquido",
    "total": 3800
  }
]}];
```

cada '*key*' é necessária para criar uma *coluna pai*
e cada *value* possui sua despesa "*name*" e o valor dessa despesa "*value*".
estou com problemas para criar um `for` que percorra essa estrutura de dados.
utilizando um `for`, ele pega apenas o primeiro valor;
e utilizando a função

```
var keys = data[0].value.map(function(d) { return d.key; });
```

eu tenho o seguinte retorno:

> ```
> [undefined, undefined, "lucro de vendas", "lucro de serviços", "lucro
> de ações", "Resultado liquido"]
> ```

onde os *undefined* seriam as propriedades '*value*' da `primary key`
e o restante está vindo corretamente.
desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: O undefined é pq não existe a pripriedade key nos dois primeiros blocos.

Comment: até essa parte eu entendi. minha dificuldade está em como percorrer todo o JSON, de forma que o gráfico seja montada da seguinte maneira:

+Margem bruta
    -gastos pessoal
    -outros rendimentos e gastos
+lucro de vendas
    -Gasto de depreciação
+Lucro com serviços...
e assim sucessivamente

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema ao percorrer o JSON
Utilizei dois foreach: um para percorrer o primeiro nível e outro para percorrer o segundo nível, se houver algum objeto.

```
var data1 = Array();
            data.forEach(function (parent, p) {
                data1.push(parent);
                parent.start = 0;
                parent.end = parent.value;
                parent.class = "positive";
                var cumulative = parent.end;
                if (parent.values != undefined) {
                    parent.values.forEach(function (children) {
                        children.class = "negative";
                        data1.push(children);

                        children.start = cumulative;
                        cumulative -= children.value;
                        children.end = cumulative;
                    });
                }
            });
```